# How to solve: console.error: "redux-persist failed to create sync storage. falling back to "noop" storage

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux-persist

I'm trying to setup redux-persist in a react native app.

However I'm hitting this error:

> console.error: "redux-persist failed to create sync storage. falling
> back to "noop" storage

I've tried to change the storage from storage to AsyncStorage in "src/redux/index.js", but it's still hitting the same error:

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

const config = {
  key: "root",
  storage: AsyncStorage // Attempted to fix it (but failed)
  // storage // old code
};
```

Here's the other codes:

In App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { persistStore } from "redux-persist";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/es/integration/react";
import store from "@store/configureStore";
import Router from "./src/Router";

export default class ReduxWrapper extends Component {
  render() {
    const persistor = persistStore(store);
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
          <Router />
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

In configureStore.js:

```
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import reducers from "@redux";

const middleware = [
  thunk,
  // more middleware
];

const configureStore = () => {
  let store = null;
  store = compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware))(createStore)(reducers);
  return store;
};

export default configureStore();
```

In /src/redux/index.js

```
import { persistCombineReducers } from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/es/storage";

import { reducer as NetInfoReducer } from "./NetInfoRedux";
import { reducer as UserRedux } from "./UserRedux";

const config = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
};

export default persistCombineReducers(config, {
  netInfo: NetInfoReducer,
  user: UserRedux,
}
```

In Router.js

```
import React from "react";
import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo/lib/commonjs";
import { Config, AppConfig, Device, Styles, Theme, withTheme } from "@common";
import { AppIntro } from "@components";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class Router extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    NetInfo.getConnectionInfo().then((connectionInfo) => {
      this.props.updateConnectionStatus(connectionInfo.type != "none");
      this.setState({ loading: false });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <AppIntro />;
  }
}

export default withTheme(
    connect(
    //   mapStateToProps,
    //   mapDispatchToProps
    )(Router)
);
```

Update:

Managed to solve the error base on mychar suggestion: [github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/issues/1080](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/issues/1080):

1. npm install --save @react-native-community/async-storage
2. on iOS, remember to perform "pod install" in iOS folder
3. Change storage to AsyncStorage

   old code => import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
   new code => import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

   old code =>
   const persistConfig = {
   //...
   storage,
   }

   new code =>
   const persistConfig = {
   //...
   storage: AsyncStorage,
   }

However, still getting this warning:

[image]

Comment: what is your react-native version ?
Did you link the @react-native-community/async-storage

Comment: 0.60.5... No I didn't like the async-storage

Comment: check this 
https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/issues/1080

Comment: @mychar, many thanks. The abovementioned error is gone, however I'm still hitting a warning, do you know how to get rid of this warning? "Warning: Async Storage has been extracted from react-native core and will be removed in a future release. It can now be installed and imported from '@react-native-community/async-storage' instead of 'react-native'. See https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-async-storage"

Comment: @user1872384, how do you remove the console error. still, I am getting console error

Comment: @mychar which console error? Do you mean this "console.error: "redux-persist failed to create sync storage. falling back to "noop" storage"? I've followed the solution in the link you've provided me lol... I've updated the steps I've perform in the question above. Remember to run pod install in iOS folder

Comment: @user1872384, still I am getting console error.
I have done all the steps. but still having the same issue. also done the pod install too. don't know why

Comment: Change the PodSpec file inside nodemodule/@react-native-community/async-storage "Rect" to "Rect-Core"and pod install

Comment: @mychar I wish I can return you a favour by helping you to solve the issue. Are you able to create a new project with minimal code to get redux-persist up and running?

Comment: @user1872384 thanks for the help, the error was solved.

Answer (score 120):

In redux-persist v6, you try changing as follows:

Old config V5 =>

```
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
const persistConfig = {
   //...
   storage,
}
```

New config v6 =>

First add: `yarn add @react-native-async-storage/async-storage`

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
const persistConfig = {
  //...
  storage: AsyncStorage,
}
```

Comment: and don't forget to do this after adding async-storage package: cd ios/ && pod install

Comment: thx... still doens't solve this though: ""Warning: Async Storage has been extracted from react-native core and will be removed in a future release. It can now be installed and imported from '@react-native-community/async-storage' instead of 'react-native'."

Comment: @user1872384 check my detailed answer why you are receiving that error

Comment: @merry_ejik what if one doesn't have an ios directory in an expo project?

Comment: Assuming your app is Expo managed(created via expo-cli), instead of using the AsyncStorage from Facebook RN Documentation use:  import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

Comment: Don't forget to remove `import storage from "redux-persist/es/storage"` line.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `@react-native-community/async-storage` has been deprecated and moved to a new organization with the name `@react-native-async-storage/async-storage` so you might as well replace the import statement in config v6 => with:  

`import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';`

Answer (score 33):

I faced the same issue, even though I replaced storage with AsyncStorage.

I solved the issue by removing the import line of the original storage

```
import storage from "redux-persist/es/storage"; //remove this
```

Answer (score 25):

Before `redux-persist` v6.0.0 you were using storage like this:

```
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
```

What this uses in background is `AsyncStorage` that was in `react-native` core.

Since `react-native` has deprecated `AsyncStorage` and will remove it from `react-native` core then the new version of `redux-persist` has stopped using it and it seems a good decision.

You can do the same now but instead import `AsyncStorage` from [community version](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage).

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
```

And then use in in your config:

```
const persistConfig = {
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  //other configurations
};
```

**Downgrading to `redux-persist` v5 is not a stable solution** since it uses AsyncStorage from core `react-native` and `react-native` **will remove it completely** in the upcoming versions.

Also I read in comments that you don't like `AsyncStorage`, well as I explained `redux-persist` has been using it as a storage so the only difference now is that you should get it from community version and not from `react-native` core

Comment: redux-persist v6 + react-native-community/async-storage => after changing that, not yet work :(

Comment: @Mahefa what issue are your getting?

Answer (score 15):

First of all import AsyncStorage using below line

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
```

Secondly the persistConfig should be assigned AsyncStorage like below and if you supplied storage object then comment it out

```
const persistConfig = {
    // storage,
    storage: AsyncStorage,  
}
```

Lastly the below line importing storage or any other storage ***should not exist*** in your file

```
// import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'  COMMENT THIS OUT
```

This is how I solved mine problem.

Answer (score 12):

For **Expo** SDK version >=33 Workflow, the plugin
`@react-native-community/async-storage` doesn't work.

It worked for me.

```py
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';`  
.  
.   
.  
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage
}
```

reference: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/react-native/asyncstorage/

Comment: What version of Expo are you using @zengod?  Could you give details of the error?

Answer (score 9):

I solve it by removing :

```
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'
```

and replacing it with:

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'
```

Don't forget this :

```
const rootPersistConfig = {  
    key: 'root',
    storage: AsyncStorage
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My error was solved by downgrading redux-persis version to "5.10.0".

Comment: Yes you can downgrade it to version lower than 6.0.0 as well

Comment: Yes but that is not suggested. Check my answer below why is that happening :)

Answer (score 2):

Comment out / exclude this line from your imports  `import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'`

ensure that only async storage is imported

`import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';`

Answer (score 1):

comment out //import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";

and import from  import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

Answer (score 0):

import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'

const persistConfig = {
key : 'root',
storage: AsyncStorage,
version: 1
}

I was going through with same problem with there was another import statement that was causing
import storage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'
is does not support es6 in react native for this cause only i have worked this code in react.js without error so, in React Native you have to use es5 version for solution

Answer (score -3):

Downgrade `redux-persist` to 5.10.0

Comment: The error does not show up in version `"redux-persist": "^5.10.0"`